# Не устанавливается laravelrus/sleepingowl на laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel5

Посоветуйте пожалуйста устанавливаю в laravel пакет laravelrus/sleepingowl.
Раньше все работало если в composer.json указана версия dev-feature/5.4 , то  сейчас пакет не ставится.

Пробовал установить версию dev-master, но она для laravel 5.5 , а у меня laravel 5.4.

```
$ php composer.phar update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package laravelrus/sleepingowl dev-feature/5.4 exists as laravelrus/sleepingowl[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.10, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4,
1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.7, 1.0.8, 1.0.9, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.10, 1.1.11, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.5, 1.1.6, 1.1.7, 1.1.8, 1.1.9, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1
.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.10, 1.3.11, 1.3.12, 1.3.13, 1.3.14, 1.3.15, 1.3.16, 1.3.17, 1.3.18, 1.3.19, 1.3.2, 1.3.20, 1.3.21, 1.3.22
, 1.3.23, 1.3.24, 1.3.25, 1.3.26, 1.3.27, 1.3.28, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.3.8, 1.3.9, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.10, 2.0.11, 2.0.12, 2.0.13
, 2.0.14, 2.0.15, 2.0.16, 2.0.17, 2.0.18, 2.0.19, 2.0.2, 2.0.20, 2.0.21, 2.0.22, 2.0.23, 2.0.24, 2.0.25, 2.0.26, 2.0.27, 2.0.28, 2.0.29, 2.0.3,
 2.0.30, 2.0.31, 2.0.32, 2.0.33, 2.0.34, 2.0.35, 2.0.36, 2.0.37, 2.0.38, 2.0.39, 2.0.4, 2.0.40, 2.0.41, 2.0.42, 2.0.43, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.
0.8, 2.0.9, 3.0.0-beta, 4.0.0-beta, 4.0.1-beta, 4.0.10-beta, 4.0.16-beta, 4.0.18-beta, 4.10.40-beta, 4.10.41-beta, 4.100.001, 4.111.001, 4.111.
002, 4.12.45-beta, 4.12.48-beta, 4.12.55-beta, 4.12.57-beta, 4.12.60-beta, 4.13.64-beta, 4.14.64-beta, 4.14.72-beta, 4.14.73-beta, 4.14.74-beta
, 4.15.80-beta, 4.15.83-beta, 4.15.84-beta, 4.16.86-beta, 4.17.86-beta, 4.17.87-beta, 4.17.88-beta, 4.17.90-beta, 4.18.92-beta, 4.19.92-beta, 4
.21.94-beta, 4.22.96-beta, 4.23.101-beta, 4.23.102-beta, 4.23.106-beta, 4.23.107-beta, 4.24.108-beta, 4.3.21-beta, 4.30.110-beta, 4.30.116-beta
, 4.32.121-beta, 4.33.128-beta, 4.33.129-beta, 4.36.133-beta, 4.37.135-beta, 4.37.136-beta, 4.37.137-beta, 4.39.140-beta, 4.4.23-beta, 4.40.0,
4.40.1, 4.40.8, 4.41.8, 4.45.16, 4.48.25, 4.5.25-beta, 4.5.26-beta, 4.5.30-beta, 4.52.35, 4.52.36, 4.55.51, 4.60.0, 4.60.13, 4.7.33-beta, 4.74.
30, 4.8.35-beta, 4.82.20, 4.9.35-beta, 4.95.29, 4.99.99, dev-analysis-8wda9E, dev-analysis-Xaw03Z, dev-analysis-zdw4bZ, dev-analysis-ze1NEa, de
v-dev-old, dev-development, 4.x-dev, dev-master, dev-new] but these are rejected by your constraint.
```

Какую версию подойдет к 5.4? 
Собственно консоль и выдает все версии пакета, но возможно кто-то на своем опыте знает какую версию выбрать?

Answer (score 0):

возможно где-то опечатка `"laravelrus/sleepingowl": "dev-development"`